# Keep window service live

Tags: c#, windows-services

My code is:
public partial class MainService : ServiceBase
    {
        public MainService()
        {

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("C:\\logfile.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine("CPU Usage : " +  System.DateTime.Now);
        file.Close();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("C:\\logfile.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine("Service Started");
        file.Close();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("C:\\logfile.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine("Service Restarted");
        file.Close();
    }
    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        TextWriter file = new StreamWriter("C:\\logfile.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine("Service stopped");
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

The code write the time of system each one second. But it run only two times(on `OnStart` and `OnStop`). How to keep it live? who explain to me the lifecircle of window service

Comment: timer1.Start() never gets executed because you enter the while(ture) loop and it never exits.

Comment: Sorry, I forget delete the while loop.

Comment: Does your `timer1_Tick` method ever output a line? Is this the *exact* code you're testing? Are you sure that the service that's running is the latest version of the code that you're working with?

Comment: It's exact my code. I am secure that the service is lastest my code . I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Please answer my other question: does your output file ever contain a line that came from the `timer1_Tick` method?

Comment: @Jim Mischel: I don't undestand your meaning. That is all my code. The proplem is the service auto end.

Comment: Can you share the content of your C:\logfile.txt before and after the execution of your service?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  This particular component is intended for UI threads that need to do some processing.  Windows services do not have UI threads, so this is the wrong choice of timer.  More specifically, the problem is that Windows services do not have a UI message pump, so the `Tick` event is never processed.  Replacing `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with `System.Timers.Timer` will give you the expected results (see below).

A few suggestions for you.

- Unless you have a pressing need to open and close the file each time you wish to write to it, I would suggest making your `System.IO.TextWriter` a class variable, open the file in `OnStart()`, and close it in `OnStop()`.
- If you'll put a call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` in your `OnStart()` for example, you'll be prompted to jump into a debug session when you start your service.  This will allow you to debug things as you move along.
- The `OnContinue()` callback does not occur when the service is stopped.  It occurs when the service is resumed after having been paused.  Thus your messages are out of place.  The "Service stopped" message should be logged in the `OnStop()` method.  In practice, I haven't seen a need for implementing the pause/resume functionality, so you might consider whether you truly need it in your service.

On with the code...

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    System.IO.TextWriter file;

    public Service1()
    {
        // Uncomment this line to launch the debugger when starting the service.
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        file = new StreamWriter("C:\\logfile.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine("Service Started");

        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Interval  = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();

        file.WriteLine("Service Stopped");
        file.Close();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        file.WriteLine("CPU Usage : " + System.DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```